# How to use qualifier to decide the fields of a class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, qualifiers

I have created to Hazelcast map config in one instance.
I have a bean method inside config which sends separate maps in 2 different methods.
Class CacheService has a field which will be injected by any one of those methods.

I am trying to use Qualifier annotation to get instance of CacheService, but I need one CacheService instance to hold a variable from first type bean method return value and second instance to have the second bean return value.
PS: I use lombok for auto constructor and injection
How can I achieve this?

I tried using Qualifiers in the @bean annotation method and create two seperate class for CacheService with qualifiers inside for fields, which didn't work.

> Config Class

```
@Bean
public IMap<String, Object> mainCache(HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance) {

        return hazelcastInstance.getMap(mainCache);
    }
@Bean
public IMap<String, Object> secCache(HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance) {
        return hazelcastInstance.getMap(SecondaryCache);
    }
```

> Class that uses bean method's value

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CacheService {

//Value that needs to be dynamic based on the qualifier
    private final IMap<String, Object> cache;

    public void put(String key, Object value) {
        cache.put(key, value);
    }

    public Object get(String key) {
        return cache.get(key);
    }

    public <T> T get(String key, Class<T> type) {
        return type.cast(cache.get(key));
    }
}
```

> Class with a problem

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class CacheCalculationInterceptor {
        //I need this instance with CacheService's variable IMap as returned by mainCache method of config class
    private final CacheService mainCacheService;
        //I need this instance with CacheService's variable IMap as returned by secCache method of config class
    private final CacheService secCacheService;
```

As I mentioned in comment I need 2 instances of CacheService class that has fields with different values from 2 different bean method. 
But I am getting "Parameter 0 of constructor in CacheService required a single bean, but 2 were found:"

Comment: put names on beans @Bean("something1") @Bean("something2") and @Qualifier("somethind1") @Qualifier("somethind2") where you need to call them. that is it.

Answer (score 1):

`@Service` defines a **singleton** bean, i.e. there is only one instance of it!!!

To have multiple instances with different injected values, you should create the instances with a `@Configuration` class, same as you're doing for the `cache` itself.

Alternatively, you could also use subclasses, e.g.

> Config Class

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("main")
public IMap<String, Object> mainCache(HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance) {
    return hazelcastInstance.getMap(mainCache);
}
@Bean
@Qualifier("secondary")
public IMap<String, Object> secCache(HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance) {
    return hazelcastInstance.getMap(SecondaryCache);
}
```

> Service Classes

```
public abstract class CacheService {
    private final IMap<String, Object> cache;
    protected CacheService(IMap<String, Object> cache) {
        this.cache = cache;
    }
}
@Service
@Qualifier("main")
public class MainCacheService extends CacheService {
    public MainCacheService(@Qualifier("main") IMap<String, Object> cache) {
        super(cache);
    }
}
@Service
@Qualifier("secondary")
public class SecondaryCacheService extends CacheService {
    public SecondaryCacheService(@Qualifier("secondary") IMap<String, Object> cache) {
        super(cache);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment @Andreas. I understand your approach, but its still throwing same error. Let me troubleshoot and look at other answers as well.

Answer (score 1):

The Lombok constructor generation will not allow you to specify the qualifiers for the two `CacheService`s instances.

To achieve that the `CacheService`s should be declared as `@Bean` with the expected qualifiers for each one in parameters.

In `CacheService` declare a constructor that accepts the `cache` parameter :

```
public class CacheService {
     private IMap<String, Object> cache;
     public CacheService(IMap<String, Object> cache){
         this.cache = cache;
     }
}
```

And declare two beans for this class :

```
@Configuration
public class CacheConfiguration {
        //I need this instance with CacheService's variable IMap as returned by mainCache method of config class
      public CacheService mainCacheService(@Qualifier("mainCache") IMap<String, Object> cache){
         return new CacheService(cache);
      }

      //I need this instance with CacheService's variable IMap as returned by     
     public CacheService secCacheService(@Qualifier("secCache") IMap<String, Object> cache){
         return new CacheService(cache);
      }
}
```

Follow the same approach for `CacheCalculationInterceptor` that requires these beans :

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class CacheCalculationInterceptor {
        //I need this instance with CacheService's variable IMap as returned by mainCache method of config class
    private final CacheService mainCacheService;
        //I need this instance with CacheService's variable IMap as returned by secCache method of config class
    private final CacheService secCacheService;

    public CacheCalculationInterceptor(@Qualifier("mainCacheService") CacheService mainCacheService, @Qualifier("secCacheService") CacheService secCacheService){
      this.mainCacheService = mainCacheService;
      this.secCacheService = secCacheService;
   }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot achieve this by using `@Service` annotation, but there is way to achieve this by using `@Bean` annotation with constructor injection

**CacheService**

```
public class CacheService {

//Value that needs to be dynamic based on the qualifier
private final IMap<String, Object> cache;

@Autowire
public CacheService(IMap<String, Object> cache)  {
     this.cache=cache;
   }

public void put(String key, Object value) {
    cache.put(key, value);
   }

public Object get(String key) {
    return cache.get(key);
    }

public <T> T get(String key, Class<T> type) {
    return type.cast(cache.get(key));
   }
}
```

**Config Class** In the define two beans of `CacheService` with respective `IMap`

```
@Bean
public IMap<String, Object> mainCache(HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance) {

    return hazelcastInstance.getMap(mainCache);
}
 @Bean
 public IMap<String, Object> secCache(HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance) {
    return hazelcastInstance.getMap(SecondaryCache);
}

 @Bean
 public CacheService getMainCacheService(@Qualifier("mainCache") IMap<String, Object> mainCache) {
   return new CacheService(mainCache);
  }

  @Bean
 public CacheService getSecCacheService(@Qualifier("secCache") IMap<String, Object> secCache) {
   return new CacheService(secCache);
  }
```